# One function for each keyIsDown

Tags: p5.js

I would like to toggle the image for each click of function keyIsDown on p5.js. Is that possible?

```
player = loadImage('player.png');
player2 = loadImage('player2.png');

function movePlayer(){
  if (keyIsDown (87) && yPlayer == 300){
    vy = -jump;
    player = player2;
  } else {
    player2 = player;
  }
}
```

When I press one time the image changes but when i click again doens't work.

Comment: I don't quite follow the expected behavior here. Are you trying to show a different image when the player is airborne/jumping?

Answer (score 1):

When you're `if` condition if met you're replacing the **reference** to the `p5.Image` which loaded `player2.png`, then in `else` you're replacing it with itself it was previously replaced with the player2.png image (hence no apparent change the second time).

You could use 3 variables:

- two to load your images
- one to swap between either of the previous `p5.Image` references

e.g.

```js
player1 = loadImage('player.png');
player2 = loadImage('player2.png');
// point the currentPlayer reference to one of the loaded images
currentPlayer = player1;
```

then:

```js
function movePlayer(){
  if (keyIsDown (87) && yPlayer == 300){
    vy = -jump;
    currentPlayer = player2;
  } else {
    currentPlayer = player1;
  }
}
```

(then simply use `image(currentPlayer,...)` to render)